# How do I change a certain value in a matrix in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, set

I'm very new to Haskell and haven't fully understood how it works yet.
In the following method I would like to change a certain value in a matrix or as it is realized in Haskell, a list of lists.

```
setEntry :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
setEntry x i j aij =
```

This is my method so far. I know it's not much but I really don't know how to continue.

The plan is to give it a matrix and then change the value that can be found in the ith line and the jth column to aij.

I'd be very grateful for any kind of help.

Thank you already in advance!

Comment: How about you start by trying to change the ith element of a list?  If you can get that, you should be well on your way to writing `setEntry` for your matrix.

Comment: Alright, I will try that. Thanks

Comment: FYI there are actual arrays in Haskell that are more suitable data structures than nested lists are for dealing with matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that there isn't really any need to make this specific to `Int`-valued matrices: the signature could just as well be

```
setMatEntry :: [[a]] -> Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]]
```

Also, instead of just *setting* it, you might as well *modify* it, i.e. the new value to put in could depend on the old, right?

```
modifyMatEntry :: [[a]] -> Int -> Int -> (a -> a) -> [[a]]
```

With that you could easily implement the original version as

```
setMatEntry x i j aij = modifyMatEntry x i j (const aij)
```

or shorter:

```
setMatEntry x i j = modifyMatEntry x i j . const
```

The nice thing about approaching it with a *modifier* than just a constant to be set it that this composes to nested lists of any depth. I.e. there's no reason to right away go to matrices, you might as well first tackle

```
modifyListEntry :: [a] -> Int -> (a -> a) -> [a]
```

and then

```
modifyMatEntry x i j f = modifyListEntry x i
                          (\r -> modifyListEntry r j f)
```

Here, the outer `modifyListEntry` works with the `[a] -> [a]` function that uses the inner `modifyListEntry` with the `a -> a` function.

Incidentally, this can actually be made shorter if we turn around the order of arguments: I'd recommend this order

```
modifyListEntry :: Int -> (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
modifyMatEntry :: Int -> Int -> (a->a) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

So, now the only thing that isn't completely trivial is `modifyListEntry`. But it's clear how, in general, to deal with lists – you're going to have clauses of the form

```
modifyListEntry i f [] = _
modifyListEntry i f (x:xs) = _
```

...or possibly also pattern match concrete values for the other parameters. Then you'll need to use recursion. Try to figure that out yourself.